# Updating a JQuery Flot with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flot

I want to push my returing data in d1 array but it doesnt happen unless I put an alert message before `d1.push...`. I tried putting `d1.push...` codes in bottom of `arr=data.split(",");`, but it didnt work neither. what should I do to put my ajax data in the chart without showing an alert box!!!????

```js
$(function () {
    var d1=[],previousPoint,arr=[];     

    $.get("../ajax/getcount.php",  function(data){
        arr=data.split(",");
    });

    alert("");// if I dont put this, my chart will be empty

    d1.push([0,arr[0]]);
    d1.push([1,arr[1]]);
    d1.push([2,arr[2]]);
    d1.push([3,arr[3]]);
    d1.push([4,arr[4]]);
    d1.push([5,arr[5]]);
    d1.push([6,arr[6]]);
    d1.push([7,arr[7]]);
    d1.push([8,arr[8]]);
    d1.push([9,arr[9]]);
    d1.push([10,arr[10]]);

 var ds = new Array();
 ds.push({data:d1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.8,order:1,}});
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

$.get is performing an asynchronous action, but you are trying to use it synchronously.  You need to put those array pushes inside of the $.get callback.  Example:

```
$(function () {
    var d1=[],previousPoint,arr=[];     

    $.get("../ajax/getcount.php",  function(data){
        arr=data.split(",");
        d1.push([0,arr[0]]);
        d1.push([1,arr[1]]);
        d1.push([2,arr[2]]);
        d1.push([3,arr[3]]);
        d1.push([4,arr[4]]);
        d1.push([5,arr[5]]);
        d1.push([6,arr[6]]);
        d1.push([7,arr[7]]);
        d1.push([8,arr[8]]);
        d1.push([9,arr[9]]);
        d1.push([10,arr[10]]);

    });
```

Comment: Thank you jack but like I said, I tried it, it didnt work!!!! that .... alert box should be written too in this case.

Comment: Then you'll have to add more information.  This is fixes the problem with the code you have listed.  If the rest of your code also contains problems, you'll need to include that as well.  

Whatever the case, if you do anything with d1, you'll need to also do it within the $.get callback.

Comment: This is the correct answer; if it isn't working, then there's some other bug in your code; please update your question to reflect having tried this.

Answer (score 0):

make a seperate function that draws ur chart.. lets say its name is `DrawChart(data)` call the function in the success handler of the `$.get()` also parse your data in the same handler.
$(function () {
    var d1=[],previousPoint,arr=[];

```
$.get("../ajax/getcount.php",  function(data){
    arr=data.split(",");
    d1.push([0,arr[0]]);
    d1.push([1,arr[1]]);
    d1.push([2,arr[2]]);
    d1.push([3,arr[3]]);
    d1.push([4,arr[4]]);
    d1.push([5,arr[5]]);
    d1.push([6,arr[6]]);
    d1.push([7,arr[7]]);
    d1.push([8,arr[8]]);
    d1.push([9,arr[9]]);
    d1.push([10,arr[10]]);
    DrawChart(d1);
})
```

problm with your code is that $.get() is async so after alert it populates data and chart is filled. and problem with jacks ans is that though hez filling the data in success handler still the code to draw the chart is being called from some where outside the success handler.

Comment: My answer was $.ajax{async:true}

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use async:false in jquery ajax function.. so youll have to just replace your existing code

```
 $.get("../ajax/getcount.php",  function(data){
        arr=data.split(",");
    })
```

to this

```
        var arr = $.ajax("../ajax/getcount.php",{async:false,type:"GET"}).responseText.split(',');
d1.push([0,arr[0]]);
    d1.push([1,arr[1]]);
    d1.push([2,arr[2]]);
    d1.push([3,arr[3]]);
    d1.push([4,arr[4]]);
    d1.push([5,arr[5]]);
    d1.push([6,arr[6]]);
    d1.push([7,arr[7]]);
    d1.push([8,arr[8]]);
    d1.push([9,arr[9]]);
    d1.push([10,arr[10]]);

 var ds = new Array();
 ds.push({data:d1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.8,order:1,}});
```

and use all your existing code as it is
NOTE:- this method is not recommended as this will stop your ui till the response of teh AJAX GET request

Comment: sry.. iam 2 used to async:true so implemented like tht.. i have edited my code again